# Jquery not changing text color after pressing enter button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a colorful textarea with jquery. It works well but when I press enter button then it is not changing color.
here is my code.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

//declearing of array of collored words
var style = [];
var words = ['function','var','editableText'];
style['function'] = 'color:#772AC3;';
style['var'] = 'color:red;';
style['editableText'] = 'color:#2A00FF;';

//function for coloring words
function ColorDiv(words,color,id)
{
for (var index = 0; index < words.length; ++index) {
$("#"+id+":contains("+words[index]+")").each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(words[index], "<span class='red' style='"+color[words[index]]+"'>"+words[index]+"</span>"));
});
}
}

//start up functions definations
$(window).load(function(){
ColorDiv(words,color,'fool');

});//]]>  


</script>
<textarea id="fool_txt"></textarea>
<div id="fool"></div>

 <script>
 $( "#fool_txt" )
.keyup(function() {
 var value = $( this ).val();
 $( "#fool" ).text( value );
 ColorDiv(words,style,'fool');
})
.keyup();

</script>
```

I dont know how to solve this.

Comment: to check for enter event ,try this $(document).on('keyup','#fool_txt',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) alert("enter");
});

Comment: not alerting anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i modified your logic. You can check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Amitesh_Bharat/ftgqsb66/9/)

```
var style = [];
var words = ['function', 'var', 'editableText'];
style['function'] = 'color:#772AC3;';
style['var'] = 'color:red;';
style['editableText'] = 'color:#2A00FF;';

//function for coloring words
function ColorDiv(words, color, arr, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/[\n\r]/g,"<br/>");
        var matchedIndex = words.indexOf(arr[i]);
        if (matchedIndex !== -1) {
            arr[i] = "<span class='red' style='" + color[words[matchedIndex]] + "'>" + arr[i] + "</span>";
        }
    }
    $("#" + id).html(arr.join(" "));
}

//start up functions definations
$(window).load(function () {//TODO: modify this to document ready and below fn param
    ColorDiv(words, color, 'fool');

});

$("#fool_txt")
    .keyup(function () {//TODO: can be optimized by selective invoking ColorDiv
    var value = $(this).val();
    ColorDiv(words, style, value.split(new RegExp("\\b")), 'fool');
})
```

Comment: it works nice, is there any way to put a `<br/>` in that div when i press `enter` in `textarea` ?

Comment: hey just append arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/[\n\r]/g,"<br/>"); before matched index. I have updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your using an undefined variable *color* when calling the ColorDiv function initially:

```
ColorDiv(words,color,'fool');
```

Is this supposed to be *style* as passed in the other calling of this function?

I have created a fiddle that I believe does what you want it to http://jsfiddle.net/ux3yph9j/
In the fiddle I've moved all the JS into a separate file to keep in unobtrusive.

The code would only work for me using $(document).ready() instead of $(window).load(). I think this as is it's in a fiddle.

Comment: If you type one of your selected words (function, var, editableText) into the textbox in the result pane, it should change colour once you have finished typeng the word.